# Jquery getting child id of a radio button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have this so far:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked=""> Radio 1 (preselected)
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
        </label>
    </div>
```

I am trying to get the id of the input when the parent label is clicked and has active class.

I have this so far but doesn't work seems to only get the first element, did use $(this) but wouldn't even respond, any help would be great thx!

```
$('label.btn-primary').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('label.btn-primary').hasClass('active')) {
        alert($('label.btn-primary > input').attr('id'));
    }

});
```

Comment: fixed question, need id of child of label sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to do it this way:

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
       alert($('input[name=options]:checked').attr('id')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
$('input').click(function() {
if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
}
});
```

Comment: doesn't work, won't even do an alert("test") outside of the if statement. Seems like input click won't even do a thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('label.btn-primary input').click (function() {
    $('label.btn-primary').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('label').addClass('active');
    alert(this.id);
});
```

On click, this will remove the active class from the other labels first, then adds the active class to the clicked label. Then, there is an alert of the id you are looking for.

If you are only looking of the input id of the clicked label, the third line should suffice.

```
alert(this.id);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kqbk7f08/1/